# How to disable the animation when activating fast user switching in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, animation

I really loathe the cube animation when using fast user switching. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: If there is a way I bet Tinkertool(http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) or Secrets(http://secrets.blacktree.com/) will have the knob.

Answer (score 1):

There is no preference/switch for this.

You can work around it, sort-of, by setting the two users up to have different resolutions or color-depths.